# can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget' Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I m using [This package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker) for the date time picker but it showing me

error: The element type 'CustomPicker' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

for the CustomePicker class [here](https://github.com/Realank/flutter_datetime_picker/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart)

```
final List<Widget> survey = <Widget>[ CustomPicker(currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.en), ];
```

Comment: The value that you're passing is CustomPicker type and the List is of Widget type that's why it is not working. Create List of type CustomPicker to store this value.

Comment: https://github.com/Realank/flutter_datetime_picker/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart#L238-L248

Comment: `CustomPicker` is a class you have in your project (or maybe you copied from their example without understanding it correctly). It is not a widget. simple as that. Read their example again and try to gain a better understanding first.

Answer (score 0):

You use class not a Widget so please use like this,

```
final List<CustomPicker> survey = <CustomPicker>[ CustomPicker(currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.en), ];
```